# Flask: expire token on logging out

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I'm using Flask with itsdangerous to implement token based login. It works fine but when user logs out with `logout_user()` call the token is still valid, causing inconsistency. So I'm trying to make the token expire too but couldn't find a proper way. Here is what I came up with:

```
def generate_auth_token(self, expiration):
    s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'],
        expires_in=expiration)
    return s.dumps({'id': self.id}).decode('ascii')

@staticmethod
def verify_auth_token(token):
    import flask_login

    u = flask_login._get_user()
    if not u or isinstance(u, flask_login.AnonymousUserMixin):
        return None

    s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    try:
        data = s.loads(token)
    except:
        return None
    return User.query.get(data['id'])
```

But I don't like this solution. Could somebody suggest a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ultimately, token-based authentication doesn't admit of easy particular invalidation.  (Universal invalidation is easy - just change the `SECRET_KEY` used to sign the sessions - every session is automatically invalidated).  There are several ways to make particular invalidation work:

1. Store a random nonce on the user's profile and reset it every time they log out.  Any token not containing the latest nonce is deemed invalid immediately.
2. Store a set of revoked tokens (remove them once they expire to prevent the set from growing indefinitely) and check each token against this set.  Add a user's token to the set when they log out and their token still has time on it.
3. Issue short-lived tokens and provide an easy renewal flow (either at the API level or in your application) so that having 5 minute tokens doesn't impact the user's experience.

Comment: @Downvoter - would you please comment so I can improve the answer?

Comment: I have several questions, first, Should I add a column to user table for persisting the nonce value in the database? Second, how can I know the revoked token was expired? Can you give more precise explain about the third way? Thanks very much.:)

Comment: Yes, that was the general point of #1.  For #2, you'd store the expiration time with the token (itsdangerous [supports getting the token's expiration time](http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/#itsdangerous.TimestampSigner.unsign)). As for #3, don't give users tokens that are valid for eternity - give them tokens that are valid for the *smallest* amount of time you can give them, and make it easy for them to renew their tokens.